# Lock on package COMMON-LISP violated When Globally Declaring Space Special

Tags: package, common-lisp

I was trying to do something like this at the top of SBCL:

```
CL-USER> (defvar space " ")
```

The error I am getting is

```
Lock on package COMMON-LISP violated when
globally declaring SPACE SPECIAL while in package
COMMON-LISP-USER.
   [Condition of type SYMBOL-PACKAGE-LOCKED-ERROR]

Restarts:
 0: [CONTINUE] Ignore the package lock.
 1: [IGNORE-ALL] Ignore all package locks in the context of this operation.
 2: [UNLOCK-PACKAGE] Unlock the package.
 3: [RETRY] Retry SLY mREPL evaluation request.
 4: [*ABORT] Return to SLY's top level.
 5: [ABORT] abort thread (#<THREAD "sly-channel-1-mrepl-remote-1" RUNNING {10025F6303}>)

Backtrace:
  0: (PACKAGE-LOCK-VIOLATION #<PACKAGE "COMMON-LISP"> :SYMBOL SPACE :FORMAT-CONTROL "globally declaring ~A ~A" :FORMAT-ARGUMENTS (SPACE SPECIAL))
  1: (SB-KERNEL:ASSERT-SYMBOL-HOME-PACKAGE-UNLOCKED SPACE "globally declaring ~A ~A" SPECIAL)
  2: (SB-C::PROCESS-VARIABLE-DECLARATION SPACE SPECIAL :SPECIAL)
  3: ((LABELS SB-C::MAP-NAMES :IN SB-C::%PROCLAIM) (SPACE) #<FUNCTION SB-C::PROCESS-VARIABLE-DECLARATION> SPECIAL :SPECIAL)
  4: (PROCLAIM (SPECIAL SPACE))
  5: (SB-IMPL::%DEFVAR SPACE #S(SB-C:DEFINITION-SOURCE-LOCATION :NAMESTRING NIL :INDICES 0) " " NIL)
  6: (SB-INT:SIMPLE-EVAL-IN-LEXENV (SB-IMPL::%DEFVAR (QUOTE SPACE) (SB-C:SOURCE-LOCATION) (UNLESS (BOUNDP #) " ")) #<NULL-LEXENV>)
  7: (SB-INT:SIMPLE-EVAL-IN-LEXENV (DEFVAR SPACE " ") #<NULL-LEXENV>)
  8: (EVAL (DEFVAR SPACE " "))
  9: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN SLYNK-MREPL::MREPL-EVAL-1))
 --more--
```

However, when I try to check and see whether `space` is defined in `CL-USER` package, it tells me that it is not.

```
The variable SPACE is unbound.
   [Condition of type UNBOUND-VARIABLE]

Restarts:
 0: [CONTINUE] Retry using SPACE.
 1: [USE-VALUE] Use specified value.
 2: [STORE-VALUE] Set specified value and use it.
 3: [RETRY] Retry SLY mREPL evaluation request.
 4: [*ABORT] Return to SLY's top level.
 5: [ABORT] abort thread (#<THREAD "sly-channel-1-mrepl-remote-1" RUNNING {10025F6303}>)

Backtrace:
  0: (SB-INT:SIMPLE-EVAL-IN-LEXENV SPACE #<NULL-LEXENV>)
  1: (EVAL SPACE)
  2: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN SLYNK-MREPL::MREPL-EVAL-1))
 --more--
```

Why is this happening? If there is a lock on the word 'space' inside the package, why is it unbound?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First: [`SPACE` is an external symbol in the `COMMON-LISP` package](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw71/CLHS/Body/d_optimi.htm#space) according to the standard.  It's not bound as a variable or function, but it's a symbol used in declarations, e.g. `(declare (optimize (speed 2) (space 0)))`.

Second: [there are a lot of things you're not allowed to do to external symbols in the `COMMON-LISP` package](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/11_abab.htm).  The standard says the consequences are undefined, and in this case most implementations will choose to signal an error.  Number 10 in particular is what's biting you:

> 10. Declaring or proclaiming it special

because `(defvar foo ...)` proclaims `foo` special.

So the answer to your question of why you can't `(defvar space ...)` is because `SPACE` is an external symbol of the `COMMON-LISP` package.  Whether it has a function/variable binding doesn't matter — those restrictions apply to *all* external symbols in `COMMON-LISP`.

You *could* get around this by shadowing `SPACE` in your package.  Then the `SPACE` symbol you're proclaiming to be special wouldn't be the one in the `COMMON-LISP` package, but the one in your own package (which just happens to have the same name).  But this would still be bad style.  [**You should pretty much always use earmuffs around special variables.**](http://random-state.net/files/nikodemus-cl-faq.html#whats-with-the-earmuffs)  `(defvar *space* " ")` will work perfectly fine (because `*space*` isn't an external symbol in `COMMON-LISP`) and will have the added benefit of not confusing anyone trying to read your code (because we'll be expecting earmuffs around special variables).

Answer (score 5):

> However, when I try to check and see whether space is defined in CL-USER package, it tells me that it is not.

The error happened not because you were attempting to manipulate a symbol `space` in package `CL-USER`, but a symbol `space` in `CL`, which is accessible in `CL-USER`.

Checking if a symbols is unbound is not the same as checking for its home package.

Is there a symbol named `space` in the package `CL` (aka `COMMON-LISP`)?

```
CL-USER 125 > (find-symbol "SPACE" "CL")
SPACE
:EXTERNAL
```

There are a bunch of symbols which are unbound, but in the CL package.